# How change default SVN username and password to commit changes?

Tags: svn, authentication, config

I need to commit my changes to repository, but on this laptop (svn configurations) I'm not default user.

How can I set my login and password as default in svn config?

OS_X 10.9
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To use alternate credentials for a single operation, use the `--username` and `--password` switches for `svn`.

To clear previously-saved credentials, delete `~/.subversion/auth`. You'll be prompted for credentials the next time they're needed.

These settings are saved in the user's home directory, so if you're using a shared account on "this laptop", be careful - if you allow the client to save your credentials, someone can impersonate you. The first option I provided is the better way to go in this case. At least until you stop using shared accounts on computers, which you shouldn't be doing.

To change credentials you need to do:

- `rm -rf ~/.subversion/auth`
- `svn up` 
  ( it'll ask you for new username & password )

Comment: I suggest not to use `-f` (force) on `rm` if it's not needed. `rm -r` will do in this case.

Comment: If you afraid to remove then just move the folder using   mv ~/.subversion/auth ~/.subversion/auth1

Comment: This did not work for me. It only asked for password and used the username with which I was logged in in Ubuntu, which is not my svn username. @FlipMcF's answer worked however.

Answer (score 27):

since your local username on your laptop frequently does not match the server's username, you can set this in the ~/.subversion/servers file

Add the server to the [groups] section with a name, then add a section with that name and provide a username.

for example, for a login like `me@svn.example.com` this is what your config would look like:

```
[groups]
exampleserver = svn.example.com

[exampleserver]
username = me
```

Comment: alroc's answer is helpful, but this is what i was looking for. thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer for global configuration!

Answer (score 7):

In TortiseSVN settings

right-click menu >> settings  >> Saved data >> **Authentication data [Clear]**

The side effect is that it clears out all authentication data and you have to re-enter your own username/password.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows (7), the same folder is located at,

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth
```

Type in the above in the Run(<kbd>Win key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) dialog box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

To check the existing username, open the below file as a text file,

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\xxxxxxxxxx
```