# How to set default username about Subversion not os name [svn]

Tags: svn

I always use git but I must know how to use Subversion.

git has `~/.git/config` for username setting.

I found `~/.subversion` directory
But, I can't find how to set default username.
When I commit, my OS username is always shown.

Could you tell me how to set?

And I also want to know shortcut command tools like scm_breeze!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How change default SVN username and password to commit changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905716/how-change-default-svn-username-and-password-to-commit-changes)

Comment: Hi usr1234567. Thank you for replying.
But, I did  `rm -rf ~/.subversion/auth` and `svn up` But, svn ask for password for Mac OS X user....

Comment: Just hit enter, it will then ask you for a user name.

Comment: Ah! I should have hit my OS's password.