# SVN checkout asks for password every time I checkout a project

Tags: batch-file, svn

While running svn checkout in a loop for many projects  , I am asked the svn userid password every time for each project. Is there a way I can ask the user the password once, and then use it everytime ?

Piece of the code :

```
For /F "tokens=1" %%i IN (market.txt) DO svn checkout checkout_directory  checked_out_location
```

Here , all the projects are listed in the market txt file. Any help will be useful . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the username and password along with the svn command as described in this question

[How change default SVN username and password to commit changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905716/how-change-default-svn-username-and-password-to-commit-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the user name and password :
[Svn CommandLine Basics](https://www.openadaptor.org/scdocs/ddUsingSVN_command-line)